# Найти сумму последних цифр

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано натуральное число. Определить сумму m его последних цифр. Если
заданное число — менее чем m-значное, то "недостающие" цифры при
решении задачи не обрабатывать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу можно решить при помощи срезов — введём натуральное число в виде строки, а затем обрежем его до `m` последних цифр. Далее можно сделать следующие шаги:

1. Представить строку в виде символов — это делается при помощи [list() (вариант 2)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-string-into-list-of-characters/);
2. Заменить все цифры из строчного типа в численный — здесь идёт в помощь [map()](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-python-map-function-ru);
3. Наконец, когда у нас есть список из чисел, мы можем его просто просуммировать при помощи функции [sum()](https://pythonz.net/references/named/sum/).

```py
n, m = input(), int(input())
if len(n) >= m:
    n = n[len(n) - m:]
print(sum(map(int, list(n))))
```

Comment: срезы поддерживает отрицательные индексы, поэтому можно написать просто `n[-m:]`. `if` можно убрать, т.к. даже если `m` больше чем длина `n`, то чего не произойдёт, он просто вернёт `n` без изменений. в `map`, `n` необязательно превращать в список

Comment: `list(n)` -> `n`. Список не нужен. Строки итерируются посимвольно.

Answer (score 5):

https://ideone.com/JQg8hP

```
def f(x, n):
  return sum(map(int, str(x)[-n:]))
 
print(f(123456789, 1))
print(f(123456789, 2))
print(f(123456789, 3))
 
print(f(123, 1))
print(f(123, 2))
print(f(123, 3))
print(f(123, 4))
print(f(123, 5))
```